# How to speed up apply method with lambda in pandas with datetime

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm new to pandas.

I have a very simple dataframe named `dlf` with an index and two columns with 40k-row. It is loaded as so:

```
d = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(csvsLocation + 'name.csv', index_col='ID', infer_datetime_format=True)
d['LAST'] = pd.to_datetime(d['LAST'], format = '%d-%b-%y')
d['FIRST'] = pd.to_datetime(d['FIRST'], format = '%d-%b-%y')
dlf = d[['LAST', 'FIRST']]
```

It looks something like this:

```
    LAST    FIRST
ID      
1   1997-04-17  1991-10-04
3   2009-02-13  1988-07-07
5   2009-10-24  1995-12-06
6   1996-04-31  1989-03-14
```

**Running this apply method takes 5 seconds**:

```
year = 1997
dlf[str(year)] = dlf.apply(lambda row: 1*(year >= row['FIRST'].year and year <= row['LAST'].year), axis=1)
```

I need this sped up because I intend to run it hundreds of times.

I suspect the issue is in using lambda.

What have I done wrong, and/or how can I speed it up?

Comment: April has only 30 days. So `1996-04-31` is no valid date. ;)

Comment: Good point. Lol. I manually scrambled the dates to anonymize the data. Apparently I overdid it...

Comment: are you going to add multiple columns (years)?

Comment: #MaxU - Yes, I will add multiple year columns.

Comment: @TimY, check my answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

You can access the the year via `dt.year` on both date columns:

```
year = 1999
df[str(year)] = 1 * ((df['FIRST'].dt.year <= year) & (df['LAST'].dt.year >= year))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         LAST      FIRST  1999
ID                            
1  1997-04-17 1991-10-14     0
3  2009-02-13 1988-07-07     1
5  2009-10-24 1995-10-06     1
6  1996-04-30 1969-03-14     0
```

You can also keep the boolean as result:

```
df[str(year)] = (df['FIRST'].dt.year <= year) & (df['LAST'].dt.year >= year)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         LAST      FIRST   1999
ID                             
1  1997-04-17 1991-10-14  False
3  2009-02-13 1988-07-07   True
5  2009-10-24 1995-10-06   True
6  1996-04-30 1969-03-14  False
```

### Performance

Measuring performance is always fun. But measuring can be tricky. If we just use our tiny example dataframe with 4 rows, things get a bit slower:

```
%timeit dlf[str(year)] = dlf.apply(lambda row: 1*(year >= row['FIRST'].year and year <= row['LAST'].year), axis=1)

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.27 ms per loop


%timeit df[str(year)] = 1 * ((df['FIRST'].dt.year <= year) & (df['LAST'].dt.year >= year))

100 loops, best of 3: 1.7 ms per loop
```

But let's have a look at 40k rows:

```
big = pd.concat([df] * 10000)

>>> big.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 40000 entries, 1 to 6
Data columns (total 4 columns):
LAST     40000 non-null datetime64[ns]
FIRST    40000 non-null datetime64[ns]
1999     40000 non-null bool
1997     40000 non-null int64
dtypes: bool(1), datetime64[ns](2), int64(1)
memory usage: 1.3 MB
```

Now we can see a significant speedup:

```
%timeit big[str(year)] = big.apply(lambda row: 1*(year >= row['FIRST'].year and year <= row['LAST'].year), axis=1)

1 loops, best of 3: 6.51 s per loop

%timeit big[str(year)] = 1 * ((big['FIRST'].dt.year <= year) & (big['LAST'].dt.year >= year))

100 loops, best of 3: 8.33 ms per loop
```

This is about 780 times faster.

Comment: This works very well and is very concise. It runs in less than 150ms on the same machine. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for `dt` trick. I've been using `python` for a while but never heard about this `dt`. Interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

I would pre-calculate `first_year` and `last_year` to simplify the comparisons:

```
dlf[year] = dlf[dlf['first_year'] <= year & [dlf['last_year'] >= year]
```

Comment: Thank you Aprillion, your solution works (at least one order of magnitude faster than mine), but Mike's is slightly faster and more concise.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly you are going to add multiple columns (multiple years), here is a **generic vectorized** solution, so you don't need to repeat it 100 times:

```
years = [1997, 2016, 2000, 1989]
years = sorted(years)

dfy = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(years * len(df)).reshape(len(df),len(years)), columns=years)

df = df.join(dfy.apply(lambda x: x.between(df.FIRST.dt.year, df.LAST.dt.year)).astype(int))

df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
```

Step by step:

```
In [160]: years = [1997, 2016, 2000, 1989]

In [161]: years = sorted(years)

In [162]: dfy = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(years * len(df)).reshape(len(df),len(years)), columns=years)

In [163]: dfy
Out[163]:
   1989  1997  2000  2016
0  1989  1997  2000  2016
1  1989  1997  2000  2016
2  1989  1997  2000  2016
3  1989  1997  2000  2016

In [164]: dfy.apply(lambda x: x.between(df.FIRST.dt.year, df.LAST.dt.year)).astype(int)
Out[164]:
   1989  1997  2000  2016
0     0     1     0     0
1     1     1     1     0
2     0     1     1     0
3     1     0     0     0

In [165]: df = df.join(dfy.apply(lambda x: x.between(df.FIRST.dt.year, df.LAST.dt.year)).astype(int))

In [166]: df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)

In [167]: df
Out[167]:
       FIRST       LAST  1989  1997  2000  2016
0 1991-10-04 1997-04-17     0     1     0     0
1 1988-07-07 2009-02-13     1     1     1     0
2 1995-12-06 2009-10-24     0     1     1     0
3 1989-03-14 1996-04-30     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, and it is quite clean, but Mike's version is about 20% faster in on my data.