# PANDAS vlookup against series with common index using map

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pb = {"mark_up_id":{"0":"123","1":"456","2":"789","3":"111","4":"222"},"mark_up":{"0":1.2987,"1":1.5625,"2":1.3698,"3":1.3333,"4":1.4589}}

data = {"id":{"0":"K69","1":"K70","2":"K71","3":"K72","4":"K73","5":"K74","6":"K75","7":"K79","8":"K86","9":"K100"},"cost":{"0":29.74,"1":9.42,"2":9.42,"3":9.42,"4":9.48,"5":9.48,"6":24.36,"7":5.16,"8":9.8,"9":3.28},"mark_up_id":{"0":"123","1":"456","2":"789","3":"111","4":"222","5":"333","6":"444","7":"555","8":"666","9":"777"}}

pb = pd.DataFrame(data=pb).set_index('mark_up_id')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I know that I can use something like:

```
df['mark_up_id'].map(pb['mark_up'])
```

to perform a v-look-up. I'd like to take the mark-up this returns and multiply it by each cost with a common index to yield a new column called price.

I know I can merge the two and then run the calculation. That's how I produced the desired output. I'd like to be able to do this similar to how you'd loop through a dictionary and use the keys to find values in another dictionary and perform some kind of computation inside of a loop. Considering PANDAS dataframes sit on top of dictionaries, there must be a way of using a combination of join/map/apply to do this without actually joining the two data-sets in memory.

Desired output:

```
desired_output = {"cost":{"0":29.74,"1":9.42,"2":9.42,"3":9.42,"4":9.48},"id":{"0":"K69","1":"K70","2":"K71","3":"K72","4":"K73"},"mark_up_id":{"0":"123","1":"456","2":"111","3":"123","4":"789"},"price":{"0":38.623338,"1":14.71875,"2":12.559686,"3":12.233754,"4":12.985704}}
do = pd.DataFrame(data=desired_output)
```

Bonus Points:

Explain the difference between the accepted answer and...

```
pb.loc[df['mark_up_id']]['mark_up'] * df.set_index('mark_up_id')['cost']
```

and why the following lambda function that i derived the above from hits an error...

```
df.apply(lambda x : x['cost']*pb.loc[x['mark_up_id']],axis=1 )
```

returns an error saying:

```
KeyError: ('the label [333] is not in the [index]', u'occurred at index 5')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
df['price'] = df['mark_up_id'].map(pb['mark_up']) * df['cost']
```

You get

```
    cost    id  mark_up_id  price
0   29.74   K69 123         38.623338
1   9.42    K70 456         14.718750
2   9.42    K71 111         12.559686
3   9.42    K72 123         12.233754
4   9.48    K73 789         12.985704
```

Comment: does this only work when multiplying two series objects that are the same length? what if the indexes were different + one series was longer.

Comment: The map will map the values of mark_up_id in df to the str_price_band in pb and return the corresponding mark_up value which you multiply by price. So the lengths dont have to be same

Comment: If you are dealing with a mark_up_id in df which doesn't exist in pb then it will obviously not be able to find the corresponding mark_up and return NaN.

Comment: looks like i was closer than I realized! didn't know that you could multiply series like that. is this the best way to perform a vlookup with a calculation in pandas? it seemed like i could probably use apply + join etc

Comment: This solution is vectorized and definitely better than apply and yes, you were just a step away :)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** for updated question:

```
In [79]: df = df.assign(price=df['mark_up_id'].map(pb['mark_up']) * df['cost']).dropna()

In [80]: df
Out[80]:
    cost   id mark_up_id      price
0  29.74  K69        123  38.623338
1   9.42  K70        456  14.718750
2   9.42  K71        789  12.903516
3   9.42  K72        111  12.559686
4   9.48  K73        222  13.830372
```

---

**Old answer:**

```
In [67]: df = df.assign(price=df['mark_up_id'].map(pb['mark_up']) * df['cost'])

In [68]: df
Out[68]:
    cost   id mark_up_id      price
0  29.74  K69        123  38.623338
1   9.42  K70        456  14.718750
2   9.42  K71        111  12.559686
3   9.42  K72        123  12.233754
4   9.48  K73        789  12.985704
```

Comment: is it possible to do this with apply and a lamba function?

Comment: @YaleNewman, yes, but it'll look ugly and it'll be slower... Why would you want to do it this way?

Comment: trying to better understand how the underlying data objects work and can be related to one another

Comment: @YaleNewman I agree with MaxU,  it is ugly, However,  just in case you need it ...I add to my answer..

Comment: @Wen thank you! if either of you could at a high level explain why the accepted solution is faster than using apply, i'd appreciate it:)

Comment: @YaleNewman I will use MaxU's answer reply here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514781/how-to-speed-up-apply-method-with-lambda-in-pandas-with-datetime

Comment: @Wen I've edited the question to pose the question. I also hit an error when running the lambda function you provided. however, i was able to get to the same answer with the code i included above

Answer (score 2):

By using `merge`

```
df=df.merge(df1,left_on='mark_up_id',right_index=True)
df.assign(price=df['cost'].mul(df['mark_up'])).drop('mark_up',1)
Out[254]: 
    cost   id mark_up_id      price
0  29.74  K69        123  38.623338
3   9.42  K72        123  12.233754
1   9.42  K70        456  14.718750
2   9.42  K71        111  12.559686
4   9.48  K73        789  12.985704
```

If you do want `apply` and `lambda` : It is ugly .....for real ...

```
df.apply(lambda x : x['cost']*df1.loc[x['mark_up_id']],axis=1 )
```

Change to (Even more ugly ...T_T)

```
df.apply(lambda x :x['cost']*df1.loc[x['mark_up_id']] if pd.Series(x['mark_up_id']).isin(df1.index)[0] else np.nan,axis=1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['price'] = df['cost'] * df['mark_up_id'].map(pb['markup'])
```

now `df` will be your desired output.