# Calculate new column across multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, view, calculation

I am new to pandas and am looking to redo the following from multiple excel sheets with multiple dataframes.

Here is the high-level structure:

**Master_df**
Master_UID | Component_ID_1 | Quantity_1 | ... | Component_ID_8 | Quantity_8

**Component_type_1_df**
Component_ID | ... | weight

**Component_type_2_df**
Component_ID | ... | weight

Master_UID['Component_ID_1'] contains 'Component_ID's from both Component_type_1_df and Component_type_2_df

Now in **Master_df**, I'd like to create column **Weight_1** columns based on **weight** out of the 2 Component_type_X_df.

multiplied by Master_df['Quantity_1'].

Comment: Forgot to mention, Component_type_X_df's do not have the same structure. Also, I am looking for a way as well to avoid merging onto Master_df but to only include new calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Master_df['Weight_1'] = Master_df['Component_ID'].map(Component_type_1_df.set_index('Component_ID')['weight']) * Master_df['Quantity']
```

Without having a data-set to play with, I can't guaranty that this will work as desired, but the map function should help get you to where you want to go.

If you don't want to append the calculated weight column to the end of master df you can do the following:

```
Master_df.insert({desired_index_position},'Weight_1', Master_df['Component_ID'].map(Component_type_1_df.set_index('Component_ID')['weight']) * Master_df['Quantity')
```

I actually recently posted a question similar to this. I posted a data-set to mess around with so you can learn the function.

[PANDAS vlookup against series with common index using map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46207292/pandas-vlookup-against-series-with-common-index-using-map)

Comment: Hi Yale! Perfect!

Comment: please accept answer if this is what you ran with:)

Comment: Hi @yale-newman! Works perfect! Just a minor correction for anybody else who comes around this solution, use '...[weight]) * Master_df['Quantity_1']' to match the question. Thanks again and I'll check your link to get my excel-brain slowly converted to Pandas :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the two `Component_type_*_df` DataFrames *do not* have the same structure, concatenate just the parts of these DataFrames that you need,
then merge the result with `Master_df`.

```
cols = ['Component_ID', 'weight']
Components_df = pd.concat([Component_type_1_df[cols], Component_type_2_df[cols]], axis=0)
Master_df = pd.merge(Master_df, Components_df, 
                     left_on='Component_ID_1',
                     right_on='Component_ID', how='left')
Master_df['weight'] = Master_df['weight'] * Master_df['Quantity_1']
Master_df = Master_df.rename({'weight':'Weight_1'})
```

Since we've restricted the `Component_type_*_df` DataFrames to just two columns,
and one column is used as the merge key, the merge only adds one additional
column, `weight` to `Master_df`.

Since you do not wish to have the merged `weight` column in `Master_df`, the
code above performs the calculation in `Master_df['weight']` but then renames
that column `Weight_1`.

Comment: Hi unutbu, thanks for your answer. Sorry, I didn't clarify but the Component_type_X_df's do not have the same structure. I am looking for a way as well to avoid merging onto Master_df but to only include new calculations.